# How to print a 3D array in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

How can I print a 3D array in a format that looks like a matrix? For example, I have the 3D array and when printing it as the following:

```
static const int nx = 4;
double Lx = 2*M_PI;
double dx = Lx / nx;

 double *XX;
 XX =  (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*nz *sizeof(double));
    
for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< ny; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k< nz; k++){ 
                XX[i,j,k] = i*dx;
                cout<<XX[i,j,k]<<"  ";
                cout<<endl;

            }
        }
         cout<<endl;
    }
     cout<<endl;
```

The above code returns a copy of each column separately instead of a 3D matrix like the following:

```
      0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239
      0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239
      0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239
      0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239       0  1.5708 3.14159 4.71239
```

Is there a function to use or what is the best way to achieve the outcome above? Thanks

Comment: `XX[i,j,k]` -- This does not do what you think it does.  In C++ arrays must have separate `[]` for each dimension: `XX[i][j][k]`.  Also, this is not `C` code -- do not tag `C` for `C++` issues.

Comment: Well, ``XX[i][j][k]`` returns the error: ``expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "double"``. I usually use the first indexing for a malloc type of array.

Comment: `XX[i,j,k]` -- This invokes the comma operator.  What this winds up with is `X[k]`.  If you want to print as if you have a 3D array, you need to actually compute the position (the index) correctly and use it.  Your supposed syntax is used in C++ 23 and [std::mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan), but it isn't going to work here.